# chisq.test Error Message

Tags: r, dataframe

Here's a problem I'm encountering:

Example Data

```
df <- data.frame(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
df <- rbind(df,df,df,df)
```

What I would like to do is find the p.value for the chisq.test of 1,2,3 vs. 4,5,6 in the data.frame defined above in the first row.

Let's try it flat out:

```
chisq.test(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))$p.value ## this works.
```

But when I try to do it by calling the columns/rows...

```
chisq.test(df[1,1:3],df[1,4:6])$p.value
```

Gives: Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length

Interesting, because that doesn't seem to be true:

```
length(df[1,1:3])
length(df[1,4:6])
```

Any thoughts on how to change the notation to get the desired result?

Comment: My hunch, is that it has something to do with the colnames, but if that's the case, the error message isn't very instructive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?chisq.test` tells us:

```
Arguments:

       x: a numeric vector or matrix. ‘x’ and ‘y’ can also both be
          factors.

       y: a numeric vector; ignored if ‘x’ is a matrix.  If ‘x’ is a
          factor, ‘y’ should be a factor of the same length.
```

If we look at `df` as per your Q, the subsets you define are:

```
> is.numeric(df[1,1:3])
[1] FALSE
> is.vector(df[1,1:3])
[1] FALSE
> is.matrix(df[1,1:3])
[1] FALSE
```

and the same for your other subset. What happens then is in the lap of the God's. What happens internally is that as `df[1,1:3]` is a data frame, it is converted first to a one column matrix, and thence to a vector:

```
Browse[2]> x ## here x is df[1,1:3]
[1] 1 2 3
```

whilst `df[1,4:6]` (`y` in the `chisq.test` function) is left untouched:

```
Browse[2]> y
  X4 X5 X6
1  4  5  6
```

and when the code calls `complete.cases(x,y)`, we get the error you report:

```
Browse[2]> complete.cases(x, y)
Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length
```

`complete.cases` calls internal code so we can't see what is going on, but essentially R thinks `x` and `y` are not of the same length and this is because they are of different types.

@Prasad provides a work around, namely unlisting the 2 data frames you supply to `chisq.test` into vectors.

However, the way you are using the function doesn't make much sense, to me at least. One would normally store the data in columns, rather than rows of a data frame. It might not appear like there is a difference, but the columns of the data frame are its components, like the components of a list. Each individual component (column) is a discrete entity, a vector of data on the /n/ observations in the data frame. If we transpose your `df` (and cast back to a data frame) to reflect a more natural data set-up:

```
> df2 <- data.frame(t(df))
```

then we can use the approach you did, but index the separate rows of the first column of `df2` (rather than the separate columns of the first row of `df`) in the `chisq.test` call:

```
> chisq.test(df2[1:3,1], df2[4:6,1])

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  df2[1:3, 1] and df2[4:6, 1] 
X-squared = 6, df = 4, p-value = 0.1991

Warning message:
In chisq.test(df2[1:3, 1], df2[4:6, 1]) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

This works, because R is able to drop the empty dimension in both subsets, so both inputs are vectors of the appropriate length:

```
> df2[1:3,1] ## drops the empty dimension!
[1] 1 2 3
> is.vector(df2[1:3,1])
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail here. Interesting to note, that is.vector(as.vector(df[1,1:3])) also returns false with no error when I tried to coerce.

Answer (score 3):

Use `unlist` when you are extracting the rows from the data-frame:

```
> chisq.test(unlist(df[1,1:3]),unlist(df[1,4:6]))$p.value
[1] 0.1991483
Warning message:
In chisq.test(unlist(df[1, 1:3]), unlist(df[1, 4:6])) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Comment: Just in case someone ever looks at this. Correct chisq code for testing a distribution in the same row uses rbind(unlist(df[1, 1:3]), unlist(df[1, 4:6]))