# Error in forecasting using nnetar function in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

This is regarding the error which i am getting while running product movement forecasting using nnetar function in forecast package. I have weekly data starting from 8th Dec, 2012. Below is the sample data which i have converted to time series.

```
      Time Series:
      Start = 2012.9363449692 
      End = 2016.32854209446 
      Frequency = 52.1785714285714 
      [1]    1    4    2    2   12    7   15   24   37   32   68   46
      [13]   72   83  132  239  216  299  290  370  519  452  343  472
      [25]  505  548  457  497  445  770  813  327  337  253  222  244
      [37]  302  720  601 1014  153   86   45   13    3    8    7    4
      [49]    4    3    2   10    3    4    1    7   10   14   32   89
      [61]   44   42   73   57   70  103  172  193  149  236  276  345
      [73]  403  608  557  537  655  704  611  578  503  597 1140  636
      [85]  309  416  385  282  211  970  937 1817  261   86   30   12
      [97]   15    1    7   13   12    7    2   10    2    6    5    5
      [109]   10   24   21   46   54   59  140   96   70  115  237  242
      [121]  205  422  336  337  390  573  329  283  328  388  438  528
      [133]  731  646  890  710  668  842  740  817  968  626 1425  337
      [145]  204   86   64   32   13   11    7    7    4    0    3    3
      [157]    2    0    4    1    6    0    4    9   22   66   68   71
      [169]  123   80  127  165  221  463  691  572  753  615
```

Below is my code:

```
   library(forecast)

   data <- read.table("./data.txt", quote="\"", comment.char="")
   series <- ts(as.numeric(data), start=2012+342/365.25, frequency =
   365.25/7)

   NNET <- nnetar(series)
```

When i run last line of my code, it gives me error: "**Error in complete.cases(lags.X, y) : not all arguments have the same length**"

I am not sure, why i am getting this error. Did i defined my time series wrongly? Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: could it have somemthing to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535706/r-apply-error-error-in-as-matrix-data-frame

Comment: Thanks for sharing me the link. But i am not sure if my issue is related to POSIXlt object. Can you please help me to get rid of it?

Comment: Is there any missing data?

Comment: No, there is no missing data. I have used the same data mentioned above. I have data of 178 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug caused by the non-integer seasonal frequency of 52.1785714285714. I've now fixed it on the github version.

Either set it to 52 and use the CRAN version, or use the github version which now rounds the frequency to the nearest integer.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have one follow up question, i have weekly data which starts from 8th Dec, 2012. According to your suggestion, can i define my time series as: series <- ts(as.numeric(data), start=2012+342/365, frequency = 52)